# In Groovy, casting between collection implementations copies source instead

Tags: groovy, collections, casting

The following code

```
void testReference() {
    List<String> source = new ArrayList<>()
    source.add("element")
    List reference = (ArrayList)source // all ok, creates reference as types match
    assertSame(source,reference)
    List copyNotReference = (LinkedList)source // should fail on GroovyCastException, creates copy instead
    assertNotSame(source,copyNotReference) // this works, copy is a different object
    copyNotReference.add("second element")
    println source
    println copyNotReference
}
```

only works in Groovy. In Java it fails on attempt to cast ArrayList to LinkedList.

In Groovy it creates a LinkedList instance, calling constructor
`public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c)`
and copying source data to the new instance.

The test outputs

```
[element]
[element, second element]
```

That behaviour only occurs when casting types that are subtypes of collections.

### Question

What Groovy mechanism is responsible for this unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy allows coercion of objects via casting them (`asType`).  This is implemented for collections.

[See the source](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/c56326a50b3e39a09d0e5dac3d513b84bc518567/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L11914-L11980)

> Converts the given collection to another type. A default concrete
>   type is used for List, Set, or SortedSet. If the given type has
>   a constructor taking a collection, that is used. Otherwise, the
>   call is deferred to {@link #asType(Object,Class)}.  If this
>   collection is already of the given type, the same instance is
>   returned.

Comment: That must be it. Both standard casting via `(CastTo)o`, and `o as CastTo` use the same mechanism. What is strange is that if you use custom type `C extends (some Java collection type)` your custom instance is created as if it had asType implemented. But it does not and standard collection's asType is used for dataset population. Too much groovy magic!

Comment: If you don't like this behaviour, explicitly override `asType`. Otherwise you will inherit the default behaviour (it's the same "magic" as you inherit `.toString()`)

Comment: I stick to my comment. I believe that most widely understood casting feature is that returned object refers to the same instance as source. With Groovy this no longer holds true, which is confusing to a VM languages programmer.